# Return checked box values to another React component containing textfield

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React js. Can anyone tell me, how to grab the values of checked boxes into another component containing a textfield? I got those values in my console from `checkedBox`
I tried this  https://jsfiddle.net/r7dm7wo0/ 
`MenuList.js`

```
const items = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three'
];

class MenuList extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount () {
        this.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
    }

    toggleCheckbox = (label) => {
        if (this.selectedCheckboxes.has(label)) {
          this.selectedCheckboxes.delete(label);
        } else {
          this.selectedCheckboxes.add(label);
        }
    }

    handleFormSubmit = (formSubmitEvent) => {
        formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();
        var checkedBox = new Set([...this.selectedCheckboxes].map(function(item){
            return(item);
         }));
            console.log(checkedBox)

         <MenuItem items={this.checkedBox}/>
    }

    createCheckbox = (label) => (
        <Checkbox
          label={label}
          handleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckbox}
          key={label}
        />
    )

    createCheckboxes = () => (
        items.map(this.createCheckbox)
    )

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="background">
                <div className="checkboxForm">              
                    <div className=" col-lg-12">
                        <div className="col-lg-6 floatLeft">
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                                {this.createCheckboxes()}
                                <button className="btn btn-default" type="submit">Save</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`MenuItem.js`

```
class MenuItem extends React.Component {
        render() {
          const { items } = this.props
            return(
                <div>
                    <textarea>{items}</textarea>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    MenuItem.propTypes = {
        checkbox: PropTypes.string
    }
```

`index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={IndexPage}/>
        <Route path="login" component={LoginForm}/>
        <Route path="menu-list" component={MenuList}/>
        <Route path="menu-item" component={MenuItem}/>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: the fiddle did not work form me. Besides, provide a code with the two components you want.

Comment: @DamienLeroux I have mentioned components above. Please check and do let me know if I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: I'm a little bit confused bu the fact that MenuList and MenuItem are on different pages. I guess that you want to do modifications on a page then see the those modifications on another page? Let me know if I'm wrong. Because the solution to your problem will not be the same

Comment: @DamienLeroux yes you are right. I wanna show the checked values in a component `MenuItem`. Iam getting those values in `checkedBox`in my console. Can you help me out of this? Suggest me how to pass the checked vales to the `MenuItem` component

Answer (score 0):

If you have data that is shared trough several pages, you have to save the information somewhere. You can save it:

- server-side: usefull to syncronise multiple pages on multiple device but you a server data base
- in [cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) or [forages](https://github.com/localForage/localForage): usefull to have the data shared between browser tabs and alive even after closing the browser.
- in an application state: useful for data related to the current application and remove when the page is reloaded or when the browser is closed. It is often use for single app like React

In your case, I think you need an application state. I suggest you to use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) that [works fine with React](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Later, you'll be able to load data from server and fill the application state to have all your page have an access to the loaded information.

If you have data that is shared trough several components in the same page, you'll need to use a  [React state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class).